# How can I get prometheus exporters running in my grails app?

Tags: grails, groovy, configuration, prometheus

I'm having trouble getting prometheus set up with my grails app. I have it completely set up and working with other exporters just don't really know where to go with the actual application.

I am trying to use the jmx exporter found here: https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter

Following the instructions on that page, it seems like the exporter gets attached to a .jar file. But to my knowledge, grails never gets converted to a .jar file? And also there's a difference I know between when grails is running in dev and production where it gets compiled into a .war file. Does there need to be separation in the front and back end? Any information would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But to my knowledge, grails never gets converted to a .jar file?

You get to decide if you want to deploy your Grails app as a `.jar` file.  If you are using Grails 3 or 4 the `assemble` Gradle task will create a `.war` file if the `war` Gradle plugin is applied in the project, otherwise an executable `.jar` file will be created.

> And also there's a difference I know between when grails is running in
> dev and production where it gets compiled into a .war file.

By default, when you generate a `.war` file (or a `.jar` file) the app will run in production mode, but you can generate a dev mode `.war` or a dev mode `.jar` file if you want to for any reason.

> Does there need to be separation in the front and back end?

There does not.

Comment: Can you deploy a web app with a .jar file? I'm under the impression that it's exclusively for desktop/server apps

Comment: "Can you deploy a web app with a .jar file?" - Yes.  For Grails when you do that we create an executable .jar file that contains the embedded Tomcat server.  With that, you can run the thing by simply doing `java -jar yourappname.jar`.

Comment: "I'm under the impression that it's exclusively for desktop/server apps"- A web app generally is a server app.

Comment: Our User Guide has some relevant info at https://docs.grails.org/4.0.4/guide/deployment.html.